# SQL getdate() in Count query not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute this query against SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tblSharesSentRequests WHERE [SentDate] = getdate()
```

This returns 0 rows, even though I have 1 row with a SentDate set to "2012-7-13"

This SQL statement works fine:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tblSharesSentRequests WHERE [SentDate] = '2012-7-13'
```

it returns 1 row.

Why doesn't it work when I use getdate()?

Comment: SentDate is a "date" field.  Not a "datetime" field.

Comment: so you can use `WHERE SentDate = Convert(Date, GetDate())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope `SentDate` is a `datetime` type variable, is it?

If so try to strip the time from date time:

`SELECT DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GetDate()), 0)`

So your query becomes:

`SELECT Count(*) FROM tblSharesSentRequests WHERE [SentDate] = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate()), 0)`

If you are using 2008 you can do as the comment states: `CAST(GetDate() as date)`.

A simpler way express it is:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM tblSharesSentRequests
WHERE [SentDate] = cast(getdate() as date)
```

The type ended up being just a `Date` and not a `datetime`.  The answer to this was to use the following:

`WHERE SentDate = CONVERT(Date, GetDate())`

Answer (score 4):

If SQL Server 2008:

```
WHERE SentDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
  AND SentDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

(Or if it is a `DATE` column)

```
WHERE SentDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

If < SQL Server 2008:

```
WHERE SentDate >= DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
  AND SentDate <  DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: +1 for all the different types, this should help any googlers out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM tblSharesSentRequests 
 WHERE [SentDate] = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score -1):

The SQL function GETDATE() returns the date and time.  You are comparing it to a field that I'm guessing has only the date.  You will need to do something like this:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM tblSharesSentRequests 
 WHERE [SentDate] = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer.

Comment: I was in the process of writing this when the other one was posted in the comments.  Sorry

Answer (score -1):

getdate() gives not just the date it provides the hour minute etc.Thus you got the 0 values as you did not have exact match. Best way to do is 
    SELECT Count(*) FROM tblSharesSentRequests WHERE [SentDate] = cast(getdate() as date)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer.

Comment: I explained him why his query was wrong.Just givinging him a query is not good for him atleast.He should be knowing what actually happening.